# trying to read an image with cv2

Tags: python, opencv, path

I am trying to read an image and assign it to a variable. It results in errors, but the tutorial I got it from had no errors in running the same code.

Code->

```
for x in range(0, 20):
    img = cv.imread(f'digit{x}.png')[:,:,0]
    img = np.array([img])
    plt.imshow(img[0])
    plt.show
```

Error->

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_4072/865484525.py in <module>
      1 for x in range(0, 20):
----> 2     img = cv.imread(f'digit{x}.png')[:,:,0]
      3     img = np.array([img])
      4     plt.imshow(img[0])
      5     plt.show
```

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Answer (score 1):

Try being more aware of where your code is looking and what it is looking for:

```
import os

# Check where we are running
print(f'Working dir: {os.getcwd()}')

for x in range(0,20):
    filename = f'digit{x}.png'
    print(f'Reading: {filename}')
    im = cv.imread(filename)
```